# Align td to first element in other td of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, center

In my HTML code, there is a table with two columns (< td >). The first column contains a label and is centered by

`vertical-align: middle !important;`

The other column contains a div and a label. At the moment, the text in the label of the first column is aligned to the center of the second column. What I would like, is that the first column is aligned to the center of the div of the second column, ignoring the label. Is this possible?

Current situation:

```
                DIV
                DIV
Aligned here -->DIV
                LABEL
                LABEL
```

Desired situation:

```
                DIV
Aligned here -->DIV
                DIV
                LABEL
                LABEL
```

Comment: Or if you do know the height of the div, you can do vertical-align:top and use line-height or padding-top on the first cell.

Comment: if you can change the table structure a little, than this should be pretty easy, if you put the first div in a separate row ... and then align the label on the left to the top of the second row. [Something in this direction maybe.](http://jsfiddle.net/7pVa6/), If you can not change the markup, javascript would be a good solution, just like @MrLister suggests. [Maybe jou can try playing with jQuery.](http://jsfiddle.net/7pVa6/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Javascript would be nice, but to my knowledge it is not possible to set a numeric value to vertical align. So how can Javascript solve my problem? Could you show an example?

Comment: in my comment above I link to a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7pVa6/2/) where I set `margin-top` of the the label on the left according to the `hight` of the first div on the right using jQuery, and using `vertical-align:top;`. There are certainly also other ways, this was just one that popped into my mind =)

Comment: Thanks guys! Both JQuery examples were very usefull and I managed to solve my problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Sh3dD/3/

You were right about the `vertical-align` of a table cell not being able to have an offset value in pixels.

Fortunately, there are other ways. The trick is to set the `vertical-align` of the td to `top`, and then to use Javascript to set the `line-height` of the label to the same height as the calculated height of the div.

Hope this helps!